# I want to update table by passing as a table type in stored procedure. Please help me to find the query to update table through stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatable

```sql
USE DBA
GO
CREATE or ALTER PROC usp_UpdateHCROutputTables
(
  @OutputTable OutputTablenamesType READONLY,
  @SessionId INT,
  @Reviewcomments VARCHAR(100),
  @ReviewedBy VARCHAR(100) ,
  @TableIds VARCHAR(100),
  @ReviewedDate DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE OutputTablenames
    SET SessionId = @Sessionid,
        Reviewcomments = @Reviewcomments ,
        ReviewedBy = @ReviewedBy ,
        TableIds = @TableIds,
        ReviewedDate = GETDATE()
    FROM @OutputTable T2
    JOIN OutputTablenames T1 ON T2.TableIds = T1.TableIds
END
GO
```

I'm getting the error likethis:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure usp_UpdateHCROutputTables, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 36]
> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with OutputTablenamesType

Please help me to find the Right query to update table passing as parameters in stored procedure

Comment: Due to your omission of whitespace and any line breaks, your SQL code isn't even valid... Get into the good habit of formatting your code. Using indentation and line breaks really helps easily distinguish specific code blocks and sections, and make finding errors far easier when a line only contains 10's of characters, rather than 100's. Good formatting, likely, would make your code far easier to debug here, and you probably wouldn't need to post a question to ask for help.

Comment: Seems your problem is how you attempt to execute the procedure and pass that specific type as a parameter. Post that code - well formatted to encourage others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

And from your previous question, you have the example of

```
EXECUTE usp_UpdateHCROutputTables 100, 'No action reqired for this',
       'Prudhvi', 1,'30/06/2022'
```

That just will NOT work since "100" is interpreted as an int and that is **definitely** not a table variable. Using Tsql, you must create a variable of the appropriate type, populate it, and then pass the variable. There is no way to pass some sort of structured literal as the UDTT. A simple example is:

```
declare @parm dbo.OutputTableNamesType;
insert @parm (...) values (1, ... );

EXECUTE dbo.usp_UpdateHCROutputTables @parm, 'No action reqired for this', 
       'Prudhvi', 1, '20220630';
```

That is a huge guess. Notice the slight improvements. Use a date format that is not subject to interpretation problems. Schema-qualify your object names. Use statement terminators.

Your previous question had the definition of your UDDT and that suggests that it contains all the columns you need to provide for your update. It that is correct, then why do you have additional parameters? It seems you haven't quite figured out which approach to take with parameter passing?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, judging from your previous question you have a table type defined like this

```
CREATE TYPE OutputTableNamesType AS TABLE (
  SessionId INT,
  Reviewcomments VARCHAR(100),
  ReviewedBy VARCHAR(100) ,
  TableIds VARCHAR(100),
  ReviewedDate DATETIME
)
```

So your stored procedure is wrong. It should be the following:

```sql
CREATE or ALTER PROC usp_UpdateHCROutputTables
  @OutputTable OutputTablenamesType READONLY
AS

UPDATE T1
SET SessionId = T2.Sessionid,
    Reviewcomments = T2.Reviewcomments ,
    ReviewedBy = T2.ReviewedBy ,
    ReviewedDate = T2.ReviewedDate
FROM @OutputTable T2
JOIN OutputTablenames T1 ON T2.TableIds = T1.TableIds;

go
```

Note that:

- The other parameters should really be part of the table type.
- You need to do `UPDATE T1` with the alias in order to do an update in a join correctly.
- Do not update the primary key `TableIds`, that is part of the join anyway.
- Is `TableIds` a sensible idea to be `varchar(100)`? It's quite big for a primary key.

You then call the stored procedure as others have mentioned

```sql
DECLARE @parm dbo.OutputTableNamesType;
INSERT @parm
  (SessionId, Reviewcomments, ReviewedBy, TableIds VARCHAR(100), ReviewedDate) VALUES (1, 'comment', 'user', '123', GETDATE());

EXECUTE dbo.usp_UpdateHCROutputTables @@OutputTable = @parm;
```